# Internet Sharing supports WEP but not WPA?

Tags: macos, security, internet-sharing

I am trying to make a WiFi hotspot through my MacBook. It has Snow Leopard 10.6.7 on it.
The thing is that when I go to sharing and then configure internet sharing, it only gives the choice of using WEP password encryption.

Is it possible to use it with WPA or WPA2? If yes, how?

Comment: I've removed your question about setting up a router. It's better to only ask **one** question per post. And beside, setting up a router has nothing to do with Apple's product, even if you connect your MacBook on it.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to use OS X's internet sharing feature to create a WPA- or WPA2-protected network [through v10.7 Lion, see below]; WEP (40- or 128-bit) or no encryption at all are the only available options.

Note that the original title on this question ("Airport supports WEP but not WPA?") was a bit misleading, as this is only a limitation on wireless networks created with internet sharing.  Mac computers can join WPA and WPA2 wireless networks, and have been able to for years and years.  Similarly, Apple's Airport base stations (except for early models) can create WPA and WPA2 networks.  It's only when the Mac is acting as a base station that this limitation exists.

UPDATE: In OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion), the normally-visible security options changed to WPA2 Personal or no encryption. WEP is still available in 10.8, but only if you hold <kbd>Option</kbd> while clicking on the Security pop-up menu.

Comment: Surely you mean that WEP is the only option near the end of the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I advise everyone concerned by the security of their wireless network
to fill a feedback at Apple:
[I need a **secure** network!](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html) about this security bug.

You have to know that WEP & WPA are just **fake** security.
There are many weapons available on the web to enter such falsely protected networks within a few minutes.

WPA2 (in fact 802.11i) is a true security function for wireless networks. Every wireless card on the market implement WPA2. It is a
hardware function.
It is up to any decent operating system to manage it.

Lately Mountain Lion permits to start a wireless network secured with WPA2.
This real security improvment isn't advertised within the many features
brought by Mountain Lion. Probably too late a move for such large a weakness.